# UseContext doesnt updates my state(probably)

Tags: reactjs, react-context

When I am in a route "/signIn" and I clicked a button there is no console.log() in my  component I have to switch to Home component and and then the console.log() works.
Why is that I thought when the state changes in useContext the  component will rerender

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import SignIn from "./components/SignIn";
import React from "react";

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

const App = () => {
  const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = React.useState(false);

  function toggleTheme() {
    setDarkTheme((prevState) => !prevState);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={darkTheme}>
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Click</button>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/signIn" element={<SignIn />} />
        </Routes>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../App";

export default function Home() {
  const darkTheme = useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.log(darkTheme);

  return <h1>kok</h1>;
}
```

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";

const SignIn = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: "", email: "" });
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (formData.name === "kamil" && formData.email === "kamilio14@gmail.com") {
      console.log("cd");
    }
  }

  console.log("hit");
  function handleChange(event) {
    setFormData((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
      };
    });
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={formData.name}
        id="name"
      />
      <label>email</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={formData.email}
        id="email"
      />
      <button>Submit </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Use context simply just dont update the state I am stuct with the original value

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console? A bit of a long shot but, could you try moving the definition of your `ThemeContext` to another file? It sounds like it could be an issue with a circular dependency since `App` imports `Home` while `Home` also imports `App`.